# Sign Up notification is not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, notifications

In `Rails project` I am using Devise plugin for authentication. As soon as a user registers he will be `signed in`. At that time Sign in or `sign up notification` is not displaying. How to `display` the `notification message` when a user signs up.

Comment: What notification? where is the notification ?

Comment: As soon as a user sign up, one notification should display saying "You have successfully signed up". This particular notification is not displaying. But when the user signs out, "You have successfully signed out" notification will display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<%= flash[:message] %>` to display the message. Override the Devise::RegistrationsController and use a before_filter to assign a message.

```
   class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
     before_filter :create_message, :only => [:create]

     def create_message
       flash[:message] = "Successfully signed up .Confirmation mail will be sent to registered email address"
     end
   end
```

Use this <%= flash[:message] %> in your post login view file where you want it to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

add this in 'application/layout'

```
<% if notice %>
   <p><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
<% if alert %>
   <p><%= alert %></p>
<% end %>
```

still not working.....

check your 'devise.en.yml' devise give default message when u sign or signup....

u must hve deleted or change this file